how child will communicate when there is multiple parents?
I have a common component which I created in the common folder and that component can be used by multiple other components.
I know that I can use an EventEmitter to inform parent components when there is only a single parent but I am not sure what to do if I need to create separate emitters to inform other parents.

https://v17.angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service?

There are few approach to get this:
1. Using EventEmitter for Each Parent
If each parent component needs to handle the event individually, you can create an EventEmitter in the common component and emit events that the parent components can subscribe to. Here’s a simple example:
common-component.component.ts:
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-common-component',
  template: `<button (click)="notify()">Notify Parent</button>`
})
export class CommonComponent {
  @Output() notifyParent: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();

  notify() {
    this.notifyParent.emit();
  }
}

parent1.component.ts && parent2.component.ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent1',
  template: `<app-common-component (notifyParent)="handleNotification()"></app-common-component>`
})
export class Parent1Component {
  handleNotification() {
    console.log('Parent 1 notified');
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent2',
  template: `<app-common-component (notifyParent)="handleNotification()"></app-common-component>`
})
export class Parent2Component {
  handleNotification() {
    console.log('Parent 2 notified');
  }
}


This approach is not very useful and too confusing (personally I don't like using event emitter)


2. Using a Shared Service
If multiple components need to be informed and you want a more scalable solution, you can use a shared service. This approach decouples the components and allows for more flexible communication.
you need to create a service for handling dependencies:
notification.service.ts:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotificationService {
  private notificationSubject = new Subject<void>();
  notification$ = this.notificationSubject.asObservable();

  notify() {
    this.notificationSubject.next();
  }
}

now every component can inject service and use it independent
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { NotificationService } from './notification.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-common-component',
  template: `<button (click)="notify()">Notify Parents</button>`
})
export class CommonComponent {
  constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService) {}

  notify() {
    this.notificationService.notify();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent1',
  template: `<app-common-component></app-common-component>`
})
export class Parent1Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.notificationService.notification$.subscribe(() => {
      this.handleNotification();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  handleNotification() {
    console.log('Parent 1 notified');
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent2',
  template: `<app-common-component></app-common-component>`
})
export class Parent2Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.notificationService.notification$.subscribe(() => {
      this.handleNotification();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  handleNotification() {
    console.log('Parent 2 notified');
  }
}


Using a shared service is often the preferred method for larger applications as it keeps your components decoupled and makes the code easier to maintain.


3. passing data using ControlValueAccessor
I like this approach and I've used it in many situations.
this one, It is worth to learn.
Using ControlValueAccessor in Angular allows you to create a reusable component that works seamlessly with Angular forms. It needs to provide NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR inside the component.
After that it bind data through formControls or ngModel. It is more cleaner compare two the 1st approach.
yo u can search for how to use NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, but this is one of tutorials:
https://medium.com/@majdasab/implementing-control-value-accessor-in-angular-1b89f2f84ebf
there are tons of other resources out there
